# How might I display a web page in a window with a transparent background using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, transparency

How can I show a web page in a transparent window and have the white part of the web page also transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a Browser control, there may be a property in it to change the background color to Transparent or to use Alpha channel layering. I'm not entirely sure how effective this would be, but it's worth a try.

Another thing to consider would be to create a small parser for the web page's HTML you're trying to view, and with that you could modify the style sheet or something to change the background color. I'm not sure you could make the page transparent doing this, however. That's all off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

The BackColor property has an alpha property, which is the same as opacity.  If it's pure html, there should be an opacity property or style.